# Prometheus Metrics getting deleted on while fetching data using HTTP APIs

Tags: node.js, prometheus

Here is my code:

```
const getPrometheusData = async function (clientId, logicNumber, ruleNumber) {
    let currDate = new Date();
    let startDate = (currDate.getTime() - 172800000); // milliseconds in 2 days
    let endDate = currDate.getTime();
    let step = "5s"
    let url = "http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=lead_allocation_status_at_logic_and_rule_level" +
        "{client=\"" + clientId + "\", instance=\"host.docker.internal:3000\", job=\"report\", logic=\"Logic " +
        logicNumber + "\", rule=\"Rule " + ruleNumber + "\"}&start=" + startDate + "&end=" + endDate + "&step=" + step;
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.data.result);
            let tmpResponse = {};
            for (let i=0;i<_.size(data.data.result);++i) {
                tmpResponse[data.data.result[i].metric.status] = parseInt(data.data.result[i].value[1]);
            }
            return {"status": 200, "data": tmpResponse};
        }).catch(err => {
            return {"status": 500, "data": "Error: " + err};
        });
}
```

I have setup prometheus docker container in my local and running it using:

```
docker run -d --name prometheus -p 9090:9090 -v /tmp/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -v /tmp/prom-metrics-volume:/prometheus prom/prometheus --storage.tsdb.retention.time=1y --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus --web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries --web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles
```

Here is my prometheus.yml file:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 10s

  external_labels:
    monitor: 'prometheus'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    scrape_interval: 5s

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
  - job_name: 'report'

    scrape_interval: 5s

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:3000']
```

Upon creating metrics, the data remains persisted for a long time. But once hit the endpoint that I have exposed in nodeJs which uses the above `getPrometheusData` function, whenever the control reaches the line `return fetch(url)`.. the metrics in prometheus are getting deleted.. This has been bugging me for quite some time.
Any insight is helpful. Thanks

Comment: How do you detect that "the metrics in prometheus are getting deleted"?

Comment: Additionally, AFAICT, endpoint [`/api/v1/query`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries) expects parameters `query` and `time`. Your parameters look more suitable for [`/api/v1/query_range`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries).